# Docker idle after restart local machine

Tags: docker, laravel-5.3, laravel-dusk

I am new to use docker configured PHPLaravel project. And am using Laravel DUSK e2e testing automation. 
Currently am running test from PHP storm.

Comment: Some times it works fine but there is an issue while run test it get idle test run occur an error. 
This case i close all container and recreate all container then it works fine, i need to know is there any way to resolve this solution. Practically its not a proper way to create container image again and again . Thanks for your Answers.

Comment: Can you put that detail in the body of your question. Maybe include an example of what you are trying to do and how it is failing?